# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de una columna con jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

trato de obtener el elemento de la primera columna de la tabla al dar clic en la fila pero no se como obtener el valor de la columna

```
<div id="tableRequest" class="table">
    <div class="row header">
      <div class="cell"> Codigo </div>
      <div class="cell"> Cliente </div>
      <div class="cell"> ubicacion </div>
      <div class="cell"> Servicio </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"> 1 </div>
      <div class="cell"> c </div>
      <div class="cell"> u </div>
      <div class="cell"> S </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

tengo esta función que le asigna el evento a cada fila pero me falta obtener el valor de la columna

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    $(function() {
        $("div.row").on("click", function(e){
            console.log($(this).text());
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
  }
```

tal cual esta te da un cadena de toda la fila pero solo quiero la primera columna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sencillo, después de que obtienes la fila haces un `.find('.cell:first-child')` para quedarte con la primera celda, entonces queda:

```
$(this).find('.cell:first-child').text();
```

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$("div.row:not(.header)").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log($(this).find('.cell:first-child').text());
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.cell {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.header {
  overflow:inherit;
}

.row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fcff99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tableRequest" class="table">
  <div class="row header">
    <div class="cell"> Codigo </div>
    <div class="cell"> Cliente </div>
    <div class="cell"> ubicacion </div>
    <div class="cell"> Servicio </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> 11 </div>
    <div class="cell"> 1c </div>
    <div class="cell"> 1u </div>
    <div class="cell"> 1S </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"> 21 </div>
    <div class="cell"> 2c </div>
    <div class="cell"> 2u </div>
    <div class="cell"> 2S </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias es exactamente lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

> Si lo que realmente buscas es hacer click en una row (fila) de tus datos que no sean el de los headers (cabeceras) y obtener todos los valores de los cell (celdas) puedes hacer lo siguiente:

#### Vanilla JavaScript

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('#tableRequest div.row:not(.header)')].forEach(row =>
  row.onclick = function(e) {
    const values = [...this.querySelectorAll('.cell')].map(cell => cell.innerHTML);
    console.log(values);
  }
);
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#tableRequest div.row:not(.header)').click(function(e) {
  const values = $(this).find('.cell').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  });
  console.log(values);
});
```

> Si por lo contrario buscas obtener el valor de la celda clicada:

#### Vanilla JavaScript

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('#tableRequest div.row:not(.header) > div.cell')].forEach(cell =>
  cell.onclick = function(e) {
    const value = cell.innerHTML;
    console.log(value);
  }
);
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#tableRequest div.row:not(.header) > div.cell').click(function(e) {
  const value = $(this).html();
  console.log(value);
});
```

---

Extra: [Función ready con Vanilla JavaScript y jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready)